# Recognize music song played to headphones (Shazam only listens to microphone)

Tags: gratis, android, music-recognition

I often listen to [a radio app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mws.worldfmradio) and when I hear a good song I want to know its name.

When alone I start Shazam and turn the volume to the max so that the sound goes from the speaker to the microphone, in order for Shazam to hear it. Very low-tech. Undoable at work or in the train.

Is there a song recognition app for Android that would listen directly to the headphones' audio output?

Comment: Note that good radio player applications show the name of the track, album and artist on the screen providing the radio station is providing it, _(most do)_, so possibly you just need to either change the settings on the app or change the app that you use to listen to the radio.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: This information is not available. I am listing to a very local Pakistani FM radio, the DJ just mixes CDs manually and probably has never imagined that anyone would listen to his small jam sessions via the Internet.

Comment: Are you able to record from the radio app, and then use shazam at a later time when it's more convenient to do so?

Comment: @holroy: The radio app does not have a record feature, but if there is a way to record headphones output then that could be a solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Genius app works fine. In settings you can select Suggest Genius Lyrics and you kinda get a notification containing name, artist and other stuff.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a link and a screenshot, thanks! :-) Rather than a notification, can I get the name of the song only when I want (usually no more than one time per day)?